# JavaScript Function is run twice?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, function, events

I'm a little bit confused.

I have a checkbox that a user can click which determines whether a Private Phone number on my page should be visible to all or only the administration. When the box is clicked I wanna make sure you are allowed to first then print the state of it just for testing purposes. And when I run this function, it's run twice.

I read somewhere else that it's because of Callbacks? But I am returning False so this shouldn't be the case right?

I am not a JavaScript wizard so there are many things I still don't know about JavaScript and its interaction with ASP.

```
/**
* Used to Check whether a Private Phone number should be hidden or shown.
*/
function ValidateHidePrivate() {
    if (scope["pickeduser"] != scope["credential"]) {
        alert("Not allowed");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert(document.getElementById("HidePrivate").checked);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<label for="HidePrivate" onclick="ValidateHidePrivate()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="HidePrivate" id="HidePrivate" value="no" />
    Hide my Private Phone Number
</label>
```

Any help?

Comment: Checkbox with label?

Comment: @Tushar I accidentally posted the question too early. Yes, it's with a Label. Just added the part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because a `<label>` with a `for` attribute raises the `click` event of `<input type="checkbox">` element that is associated for when clicked.

You should bind `click` event handler to `input`, not to `label`.

```js
function ValidateHidePrivate() {
      alert();
}
```

```html
<label for="HidePrivate" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="HidePrivate" onclick="ValidateHidePrivate()" id="HidePrivate" value="no" />
    Hide my Private Phone Number
</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you click your label, may it be  there is event click runs also on checkbox? 
Try to add `event.stopPropagation()` inside your function.

Comment: It's still run twice even after adding that.

Comment: It worked for me, I'm programming an extension for Chrome, and I'm using Jquery. I used the same command in my event and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick` event handler in only on `input`.  Also the `input` is nested inside label .

Hope this snippet will be useful

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="HidePrivate" id="HidePrivate" value="no" onclick="ValidateHidePrivate()" />

<label for="HidePrivate">
  Hide my Private Phone Number
</label>
```

**JS**

```
function ValidateHidePrivate() {
  // rest of code
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/db6k76q1/)